# User creation with mutiple command options

Tags: command-line, user-management

Is it possible to create a user with specific default home directory and add the user to specific primary group with single command?

Comment: No, you need 2 commands for that (question answered). Mind though: please rephrase the question, you are asking for a yes or no answer. A better question would be to ask HOW to do what you want to do. You will get an informative answer that can help you and feature readers.

Comment: @Rinzwind You're proven wrong.

Comment: @ByteCommander sudo and adduser are two commands :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `useradd`. I added the line to prove that it is possible. In general running `passwd` afterwards when doing it manually is more secure and the best way to go.

```bash
sudo useradd -U -m -G <group> -p <password> <user-name>
```

From [`man useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/useradd):

> ```
>    -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
>        A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of.
>        Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no
>        intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same
>        restrictions as the group given with the -g option. The default is
>        for the user to belong only to the initial group.
>
>    -m, --create-home
>        Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files
>        and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be
>        defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.
>
>        By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not
>        enabled, no home directories are created.
>
>    -U, --user-group
>        Create a group with the same name as the user, and add the user to
>        this group.
>
>        The default behavior (if the -g, -N, and -U options are not
>        specified) is defined by the USERGROUPS_ENAB variable in
>        /etc/login.defs.
>
>    -p, --password PASSWORD
>        The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to
>        disable the password.
>
>        Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or
>        encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
>
>        You should make sure the password respects the system's password
>        policy.
> ```

So you should better do it in two steps, this way the password does not get logged by the system.

```
sudo useradd -U -m -G <group> <user-name>
sudo passwd <user-name>
```

And you can get even this into a one line action:

```
sudo useradd -U -m -G <group> <user-name> && sudo passwd <user-name>
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can accomplish this with a single command by using the friendlier frontend `adduser` instead of `useradd`.

```
sudo adduser --home /path/to/desired/homedirectory --ingroup specialgroup  newuser
```

Comment: Was just about to type the same... :P